# Override initialize method of a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to override initialize method of a gem as:

```
# rails_app_folder/lib/redis/unique/queue.rb

require "redis"

class Redis
  module Unique
    class Queue

      def initialize(name, redis_or_options = {})
        #Custom logic..
      end

    end
  end
end
```

However, when I create an new instance `Redis::Unique::Queue.new` the constructor in the gem folder is executed instead.

Any idea?

Comment: Put the code containing your custom `initialize` method in a separate module e.g. `QueueExtension` and call `Redis::Unique::Queue.prepend(QueueExtension)` to add it. That way, you keep the original method and it allows you to call `super` to invoke it.

Comment: What @Stefan said, plus I would place this in `config/initializers/` instead of `lib/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the method, you can move your custom implementation into a separate module and [`prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html#prepend-method) it to the `Queue` class:

```
# config/initializers/queue_extension.rb

module QueueExtension
  def initialize(name, redis_or_options = {})
    # Custom logic

    super # <- as needed, invokes the original Redis::Unique::Queue#initialize
  end
end

Redis::Unique::Queue.prepend(QueueExtension)
```

Using `prepend` puts the code "in front" of the existing code.

If `Redis::Unique::Queue` is not available at that point, you might have to `require` it.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion of prepending using module, its much better than overwriting.